# Não consigo utilizar as funções que exportei com o modulo!

Tags: javascript, webpack

ao utilizar o export default class no javascript, 
não estou conseguindo usar as funções que importei.

**Retorno no inspect do navegador**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue arquivos:

**index.js**

```
/* global fetch */
import API_URL from './config';
import toJSON from './utils';
import album from './album';
import search from './search';
// const API_URL = require('./config');
// const toJSON = require('./utils');
// const album = require('./album');
// const search = require('./search');


export default class SpotifyWrapper {
  constructor(options) {
    this.apiURL = options.apiURL || API_URL;
    this.token = options.token;

    this.album = album.bind(this)();
    this.search = search.bind(this)();
  }

  static request(url) {
    const headers = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `'Bearer ${this.token}'`,
      },
    };

    return fetch(url, headers).then(toJSON);
  }
}
```

**album.js**

```
export default function album() {
  return {
    getAlbum: id => this.request(`${this.apiURL}/albums/${id}`),
    getAlbums: ids => this.request(`${this.apiURL}/albums/?ids=${ids}`),
    getAlbumTracks: id => this.request(`${this.apiURL}/albums/${id}/tracks`),
  };
}
```

**search.js**

```
function searcher(type, query) {
  return this.request(`${this.apiURL}/search?q=${query}&type=${type}`);
}

export default function search() {
  return {
    artists: searcher.bind(this, 'artist'),
    albums: searcher.bind(this, 'album'),
    tracks: searcher.bind(this, 'track'),
    playlists: searcher.bind(this, 'playlist'),
  };
}
```

**utils.js**

```
const toJSON = data => data.json();
export default toJSON;
```

**config.js**

```
const API_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';
export default API_URL;
```

**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
import { join } from 'path';

const include = join(__dirname, 'src');

export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './index',
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'spotifyWrapper',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
    ],
  },
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Spotify Wrapper Test</title>
</head>
<body>



  <script src="../dist/spotify-wrapper.umd.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```